# Laravel 4 - Setting session on page load

Tags: php, session, laravel

so I am trying to figure out how to do this, I am learning how to use Laravel as well as trying to work on a clients project with it (Only way I can learn...). The client requests the following:

- When a user loads the website, check if he has logged in, if not,
  give him a random username and password.

Now, I've been trying to research how to do this, with the random username and password, I would simply use `str_random()`, use `auth::attempt` to log the user in, but I am lost on how to create a session if he doesn't have one. I know `filters` can help me out here, I just can't figure it out. Can I have some advice here? If I was use to use a controller, what would be an example?

Comment: Can you give a little background on why you need to assign a random username and password. It doesn't seem to make sense. If they aren't logged in normally a login page would display. If you do indeed need to create a random username and password you would have to add those items to the database then attempt to log them in.

Comment: It's what the client wants, really, I agree with you, but yes, I got the database stuff figured out. I'm confused with the authentication and assigning sessions.

Comment: After setting database info then submit the same way as if someone were logging in to the site.

Comment: Example? How would I set it? Routes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have properly created a 'users' table with the columns you want.  You can use Laravel's built in Authentication system to check if the user is logged in or not.  In your case, it sounds like if the user is not logged in, you want to go ahead and create a random user and log in with that.  Here is a commented code sample that should help you out.

As far as sessions go, if you're using Laravel's built in authentication...you don't have to worry about sessions at all, Laravel handles it all for you.

**Edit**

This all would be done in a controller.

```
<?php

// First ask Laravel if the user is logged in.
if (Auth::guest())
{
    // If not, let's create a new user, save it, then log in with that newly created user.
    $newUser = new User;
    $newUser->username = str_random();
    $newUser->password = Hash::make(str_random());

    $newUser->save();

    // This login() function allows us to just login someone in without any hassle.
    // If you were collecting and checking login credentials, that's when you would use attempt()
    Auth::login($newUser)
}
else
{
    // He is already logged in.  You can then access his user information like so...
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->username; // Would return his username.
}

// At this point, the user is defintely logged in one way or another.  So we can then send the view as normal.
return View::make('members.home');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - what class would this be under, I assume controller name would be like UserController? I was also told that the before filter would also help me in this case.....